# Java: Changing loop counter value inside the loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

If i have a loop (any loop)..lets say a for loop for now:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
```

if, within an iteration of the loop, i say:

```
x=50;
```

Will the next iteration of the loop jump to counter 50? Or does any change to the value of x within the loop not affect the loop counter?

Comment: Yes it will change the loop counter. Testing it is trivial and would probably have taken less time than writing the question ;)

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis, that question is not helpful. The two questions are un-related.

Comment: You can reply with `@username` otherwise that user will not get notified. I think that one answers your question. If not, [this one must](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450056/how-does-a-for-loop-check-its-conditions-in-java?rq=1). If someone would be so kind as to reopen and reclose.

Comment: Are you still having trouble understanding the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite the for loop below as a do-while loop.

```
for (int x=0; x<100; x++) 
cout << x << " "; 
int x=0; 
 do { 
 cout << x << " "; 
 x++; 
 } while (x<100);
```

Same for 50