# for loops in java and values of i

Tags: java

In Horstmann's textbook(Big Java Late Objects) on java, for a for loop  such as :

```
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
```

Horstmann says that values of `i` for this for loop is `0 1 2 3 4 5` .

However, it seems to me that the value of `i` should end at 6 since the loop is entered when the `i` has the value 5 . What am I not understanding about this loops could someone explain me?

(PS. I am sorry if the question is too basic and thus not allowed in this platform.)

edit about the duplicate suggestion: My question is not a duplicate of the suggested link because the suggested link is about the execution of the for loop, mine is about the updating of the variable i , after the end of the execution. I understand that if I would add a System.out.print(i) statement the output will be 0 1 2 3 4 5 because i gets updated after the execution statement (in this case the print statement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a for loop check its conditions in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450056/how-does-a-for-loop-check-its-conditions-in-java)

Comment: Yes, but the accepted answer in the duplicate also states that the update of `i` is executed after the execution of the body (before the termination condition). The author of that question originally asked why the loop printed `i=5` when the condition was set to `i<5` (which was because the author had combined the print statement with the increment part.

Comment: That is a compelling answer, and I am willing to delete this question, due to it being a duplicate. However I also think that I should not because @Roger Lindsjö's  answer is more illuminating the ones that were given as an answer to the suggested post. In that case it appears to me as though there is a tie, and I am willing to act in accordance to a tie breaking suggestion .

Comment: I think you should consider this the difference between what is observable (highest value of `i` seen inside the loop body is 5) and what happens 'under the hood' (`i` becomes 6 so the loop terminates)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that the value of `i` will be 6 after the loop has terminated, but perhaps Horstmann meant the values of `i` inside the loop?

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("Value of i IN loop: " + i);
}
System.out.println("Value of i AFTER loop: " + i);
```

Output:

```
Value of i IN loop: 0
Value of i IN loop: 1
Value of i IN loop: 2
Value of i IN loop: 3
Value of i IN loop: 4
Value of i IN loop: 5
Value of i AFTER loop: 6
```

And it is customary to declare the "counter" for the loop in the loop unless the value when terminating is needed afterwards.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
}
// i is not available here
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, afterall it reminded me that the i variable only exists inside the foor loop and "dies" when the loop is no longer executed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the anatomy of a `for` loop in Java (similar applies to C/C++ and a few other languages as well)

```
for (int i=0; i <= 5; ++i)

int i=0     initial condition; happens before the loop starts
i <= 5      check is performed BEFORE each iteration of the loop
++i         loop variable is incremented AFTER each iteration
```

So, your `for` loop would iterate 5 times, and at the end of the fifth iteration, `i` would be incremented to 6.  At that point, the `i <= 5` check would happen one last time, and it would fail, since 6 is greater than 5.

To convince yourself of all this, run the following Java code:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i <= 5; ++i) {
    // empty
}
System.out.println(i);
```

You will see that the value of `i` after the loop in fact is 6.

Comment: This is more detailed answer then mine, Nice job

Answer (score 1):

This loop

```
for ( i = 0; i <=5; i ++)
```

is like

```
int i = 0;

while (i <= 5){  // Exits when i > 5

   ...

   i++;
} // goes back to while-loop check
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of I will end at 5, Because you are doing `i <= 5` It checks if I is greater or equal to 5 and then ends the loop. hence making it end at 5 and not 6.

Answer (score 0):

Well the man is right!
it iterates from 0 to 5, because...
1. the condition is „i <= 5“ 
2. Java is 0 indexed, or to be exact by declaring and initialising the variable i = 0, it will start iterating from 0 until the condition returns false. 
The decisive point here is the conditional pressure inside the for-loop
You understand?

Answer (score 0):

This is the working sequence with values to see what exactly happens:

```
i=0 

//tasks

i++ 

i=1 check i<=5 //ok

//tasks

i++

i=2 check i<=5 //ok 
//tasks

i++

i=3 check i<=5 //ok 
//tasks

i++

i=4 check i<=5 //ok 
//tasks

i++

i=5 check i<=5 //ok 
//tasks

i++

i=6 check i<=5 //it's not ok

// exit the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the value of `i` gets incremented to `6`, and then the loop condition does not get satisfied,and the loop exits. However, the author is trying to convey that the values of `i` for which the `for` loop block will get executed, are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop will end in `5` since the condition on your loop is `i<=5`, meaning the loop will stop if it reaches the number `5`.